# Pushing to private docker registry fails

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a private docker registry. I cloned the git repository and ran it.

Then I pulled the base image from docker and tagged it as instructed on [Sam Alba's guide](http://blog.docker.io/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/).

```
sudo docker pull base
sudo docker tag b750fe79269d localhost:5000/base
```

I pushed the image to the local repository following are what I got from docker and the docker registry respectively.

```
sudo docker push localhost:5000/base

The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/base] (len: 1)
Processing checksums
Sending image list
Pushing repository localhost:5000/base (1 tags)
Pushing 27cf784147099545
Buffering to disk 78093344/? (n/a)
Pushing 78.09 MB/78.09 MB (100%)
```

The log from docker-registry when I push

```
"127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:12:30:29] "GET /v1/_ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "Go 1.1 package http"
2013-09-12 12:30:29,033 INFO: "127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:12:30:29] "GET /v1/_ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "Go 1.1 package http"
2013-09-12 12:30:29,042 DEBUG: check_session: Session is empty
"127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:12:30:29] "PUT http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/base/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "docker/0.5.3 go/go1.1 kernel/3.9.0-0-generic"
2013-09-12 12:30:29,045 INFO: "127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:12:30:29] "PUT http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/base/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "docker/0.5.3 go/go1.1 kernel/3.9.0-0-generic"
2013-09-12 12:30:29,048 DEBUG: check_session: Session is empty
2013-09-12 12:30:29,049 DEBUG: api_error: Image not found
"127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:12:30:29] "GET /v1/images/27cf784147099545/json HTTP/1.1" 404 34 "-" "Go 1.1 package http"
2013-09-12 12:30:29,051 INFO: "127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:12:30:29] "GET /v1/images/27cf784147099545/json HTTP/1.1" 404 34 "-" "Go 1.1 package http"
2013-09-12 12:30:29,056 DEBUG: check_session: Session is empty
"127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:12:30:29] "PUT /v1/images/27cf784147099545/json HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "docker/0.5.3 go/go1.1 kernel/3.9.0-0-generic"
2013-09-12 12:30:29,059 INFO: "127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:12:30:29] "PUT /v1/images/27cf784147099545/json HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "docker/0.5.3 go/go1.1 kernel/3.9.0-0-generic"
2013-09-12 12:32:00,811 DEBUG: check_session: Session is empty
2013-09-12 12:32:01,764 DEBUG: put_image_layer: Error when computing tarsum invalid header
2013-09-12 12:32:01,764 DEBUG: put_image_layer: Wrong checksum
2013-09-12 12:32:01,764 DEBUG: api_error: Checksum mismatch, ignoring the layer
"127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:12:32:01] "PUT /v1/images/27cf784147099545/layer HTTP/1.1" 400 56 "-" "docker/0.5.3 go/go1.1 kernel/3.9.0-0-generic"
2013-09-12 12:32:01,778 INFO: "127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:12:32:01] "PUT /v1/images/27cf784147099545/layer HTTP/1.1" 400 56 "-" "docker/0.5.3 go/go1.1 kernel/3.9.0-0-generic"
```

Comment: Could you add command or config file which you run docker registry? Are you sure that is not a problem with using sudo to run docker?

Answer (score 1):

First thing would be to test with the last version of Docker (0.6.1). Feel free to open a issue on https://github.com/dotcloud/docker

Answer (score 0):

Just try to run docker tag base & push to private registry because docker push can't understand anything other then name of image or repository.

$ sudo docker pull base

$ sudo docker tag base localhost:5000/base

$ sudo docker push localhost:5000/base